# Laravel sends SQL request to the wrong table without reason

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with Laravel, let me describe all steps.

1. Created migration "**create_user_role_table**" with:

   $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
   $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
2. Created **Role** and **UserRole** models
3. In **UserRole** model:

   protected $table = "user_role";
   protected $guarded = false;
4. In Role and User models added function belongsToMany.
5. IndexController: $user = User::find(1); dd($user->role[0]->title);

After those steps, laravel without reason trying to open "role_user" table, not "user_role". Where did he find this table in the code? "**SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'blog.role_user' doesn't exist**". If rename table in DataBase to "role_user", it's work. How to solve that, where did he found table with name "role_user"?

Comment: "_without reason_"? Read up on [Table Structure](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-table-structure) for relationships

Answer (score 3):

Laravel's naming convention for pivot tables is snake_cased model names in alphabetical order separated by an underscore. So, if one model is `User`, and the other model is `Role`, the pivot table will be `role_user`.

You are free to use any table name you want (such as `user_role`), but you will then need to specify the name of the pivot table in the relationship. This is done using the second parameter to the `belongsToMany()` function.

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'user_role', 'user_id', 'role_id');
```